# How compare output returned from powershell cmdlet with a string

Tags: string, powershell, compare

I have the following code:

```bsh
$RecipientType = Get-Recipient $Name | Select-Object -Property RecipientType

if ($RecipientType.Equals("UserMailbox")) {
    Write-Host "Mailbox is OnPrem"          
}
```

I want to compare `RecipientType` value with string `"UserMailbox"`, but it's not working...

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using `.Equals()`, and not `-eq` (or `-ceq` is you need case sensitive comparison)?

Comment: -eq will also work. we can use both -eq and .Equals(). -ceq is used in case of case sensitivity.

Comment: I know that, but I'm asking whether there's a particular reason in this specific scenario

Comment: No nothing specific. Main focus is to use  Select -ExpandProperty instead of Select-Object -Property in this case

Comment: `Select` and `Select-Object` is the same cmdlet (`Select` is just an alias)

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity I'd use this:

```
if ((Get-Recipient $identity).RecipientType -eq 'usermailbox') {
  Write-Host 'Mailbox is OnPrem'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here instead of using **Select-Object -Property**, use **Select-Object -ExpandProperty** because Select-Object returns an object. It can be done as below:

```bsh
$RecipientType = (Get-Recipient $Identity | Select-Object -ExpandProperty RecipientType)

if ($RecipientType.Equals("UserMailbox")) {
    Write-Host "Mailbox is OnPrem"          
}
```